# How to Count Duplicate Values in One Table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, duplicates

I have a view with the following table/sample values:

```
ParentID, ChildContainerID, ChildID
1         CCID1                CID1
1         CCID1                CID2
1         CCID2                CID1
1         CCID2                CID2
1         CCID2                CID3
2         CCID3                CID1
2         CCID3                CID2
2         CCID3                CID2
2         CCID4                CID5
2         CCID4                CID2
2         CCID5                CID5
```

My goal is to craft a query that would only return the duplicate child's across the parent id (disregarding the childcontainerid)

So for my example data above I would like the following result

```
ParentID, ChildID, CountChildID
1         CID1     2
2         CID2     3
2         CID5     2
```

I've tried a number of different queries but they aren't working and I think I'm just frustrated and overlooking something simple at this point.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT ParentID,
       ChilID,
       COUNT(*) CountChildID
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY ParentID,
         ChilID
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Comment: Yep, too complicated in my head haha. Thanks.

Comment: @BobFishel Please don't edit your question with a new requirement.  Ask a new question with the new requirements.

Comment: @BobFishel If you really need it, you should change the `HAVING` clause with this: `HAVING(COUNT DISTINCT ChildContainerID) > 1`

Comment: Ok will do @bluefeet sorry! Thanks @lamak!